# Calcutation at SQL level

Tags: functions, count

I have this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(lead_status) as 'Pending files'
  FROM vw_file_registrationlist
  WHERE lead_status_id = "1" || lead_status_id="2" || lead_status_id="4" || lead_status_id="5" || lead_status_id="6"
)A,
(
  SELECT COUNT(lead_status) as 'Completed files'
  FROM vw_file_registrationlist
  WHERE lead_status_id = "3"
)B
, (
  select DISTINCT employee_name
  From vw_file_registrationlist
  where employee_name='anna'
)C
```

I am getting the result as

```
Name  Pending files  Completed files
----  -------------  ---------------
anna  3              2
```

I need to calculate the `pending files / total files * 100`. Is it possible?

Comment: what database are you using?

Comment: Your where statement is invalid SQL. `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL - if you think that is an `OR` you are mistaken. And double quotes are for identifiers, so `"1"` refers to a column named `"1"`. So your `where` statement concatenates the boolean result of comparing the column `lead_status_id` to the columns `"1"`, `"2"`, ...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Some products [do implement "invalid" SQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or).

Comment: @anna: Are you using MySQL? Or perhaps MariaDB?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't right,

```
WHERE lead_status_id = "1" || lead_status_id="2" || lead_status_id="4" || lead_status_id="5" || lead_status_id="6"
```

What you want is,

```
WHERE lead_status_id IN (1,2,4,5,6);
```

Seriously, learn to use whitespace and take some pride in your code. Pick a convention (capitalize all sql tokens, and lower case all of your identifiers) Even if you don't get sql who writes like that..

```
)a
)b
```

Where did you even get that from? .. `SELECT (...) AS t, (...) AS x` whitespace, and `AS`! That all said, I think you want something like this,

```
SELECT
  count(lead_status) FILTER (WHERE lead_status_id IN (1,2,4,5,6)) as 'Pending files',
  count(lead_status) FILTER (WHERE lead_status_id = 3) AS 'Completed files',
  any(employee_name = 'anna') AS has_anna
FROM vw_file_registrationlist;
```

Comment: Thanks                                                                                                               This one is working fine for me                                                                                    SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(lead_status) as 'Pending files' FROM vw_file_registrationlist WHERE lead_status_id IN(1,2,4,5))A , (SELECT COUNT(lead_status) as 'Completed files' FROM vw_file_registrationlist WHERE lead_status_id = "3" )B, (select DISTINCT employee_name From vw_file_registrationlist where employee_name='anna')C

Comment: I am getting the result as

Name  Pending files  Completed files
----  -------------  ---------------
anna  3              2

I need to calculate the pending files / total files * 100. Is it possible? plz help me

Answer (score 0):

You provided an answer to the request to provide the DBMS you're working in, which makes it difficult to provide SQL that will definitely work for you.

Whatever the DBMS, something akin to what Even Carroll presented should perform better than your original query, as it's executing a single query, not three separate ones.

I'm going to rework his query into what I believe will be a more generic form (I usually work in SQL Server, and I don't think everything he's doing works there).

```
SELECT 'anna' as [Name]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN lead_status IS NULL THEN 0
                WHEN lead_status_id IN (1,2,4,5,6) THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END) AS 'Pending files'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN lead_status IS NULL THEN 0
                WHEN lead_status_id = 3 THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END) AS 'Completed files'
  FROM vw_file_registrationlist
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vw_file_registrationlist WHERE employee_name = 'anna')
;
```

Now, this should do the following:

- If there are no records where `employee_name` is `'anna'`, no row is returned.
- Otherwise, it returns:

  - `'anna'`
  - the count of rows where `lead_status_id` is 1, 2, 4, 5, or 6, and where `lead_status` is not NULL
  - the count of rows where `lead_status_id` is 3, and where `lead_status` is not NULL

The `COUNT()` function, when operating on an individual column (rather than `COUNT(*)`), counts the number of non-NULL occurrences of that column. Since I'm filtering the data with the `CASE` statement and `SUM`ming the value 1 for each row that should be counted, I needed to make sure I didn't count rows where `lead_status` was NULL manually. If you want all rows, regardless of whether `lead_status` is NULL or not, or if `lead_status` is a `NOT NULL` column, you can eliminate the `WHEN lead_status IS NULL THEN 0` parts.

OK, now to get your calculated value. You have two options:

### Directly calculate the value using the aggregate functions in an equation:

```
SELECT 'anna' as [Name]
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN lead_status IS NULL THEN 0
                WHEN lead_status_id IN (1,2,4,5,6) THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END) AS 'Pending files'
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN lead_status IS NULL THEN 0
                WHEN lead_status_id = 3 THEN 1
                ELSE 0 END) AS 'Completed files'
      , SUM(CASE WHEN lead_status IS NULL THEN 0
                 WHEN lead_status_id IN (1,2,4,5,6) THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 END)
       /SUM(CASE WHEN lead_status IS NULL THEN 0
                 WHEN lead_status_id = 3 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0 END)
       *100 AS 'Calculated Value'
  FROM vw_file_registrationlist
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vw_file_registrationlist WHERE employee_name = 'anna')
;
```

This should get you the answer you want. However, it's not great from a maintenance standpoint (you've got to make changes twice if the definitions for pending or completed files ever changes), and it can get hard to follow. So, there's also:

### Wrap the query in another query to perform the final calculations:

```
SELECT employee_name AS 'Name'
      ,pending_count AS 'Pending files'
      ,completed_count AS 'Completed files'
      ,(pending_count * 100 / completed_count) AS `Calculated value'
  FROM (
        SELECT 'anna' as employee_name
              ,SUM(CASE WHEN lead_status IS NULL THEN 0
                        WHEN lead_status_id IN (1,2,4,5,6) THEN 1
                        ELSE 0 END) AS pending_count
              ,SUM(CASE WHEN lead_status IS NULL THEN 0
                        WHEN lead_status_id = 3 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0 END) AS completed_count
          FROM vw_file_registrationlist
         WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM vw_file_registrationlist WHERE employee_name = 'anna')
   ) t
;
```

This simply lets you write your equation with the column names from the subquery, instead of having to use the full aggregate expressions. Since the expressions are now only used once, the potential maintenance issue is gone. Plus, this is much more readable.

Either one should work. It's possible one or the other will perform better; if there's going to be a large number of rows returned (instead of one row, as in your example), the first option (use the aggregate values directly in the calculation) would probably perform better. That said, even then the difference is likely to be small enough that the maintenance benefits of the second option probably make it better in practice.